# What does `git checkout -b new-feature master` do?

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-merge) and I'm confused about the fast-forward merge example, where it does the following:

```
# Start a new feature
git checkout -b new-feature master
# Edit some files
git add <file>
git commit -m "Start a feature"
# Edit some files
git add <file>
git commit -m "Finish a feature"
# Merge in the new-feature branch
git checkout master
git merge new-feature
git branch -d new-feature
```

What does the second line do? How is it different from `git checkout -b new-feature`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
git checkout -b new-feature master
```

will create a new branch called `new-feature master` from `master` *and* also checkout that new branch.

Check the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) for more information:

```
git checkout -b|-B <new_branch> [<start point>]
```

If the `<start point>` is omitted, then the current branch is used as the starting point.

Comment: Oh, I thought `master` was the fourth argument of `git`. Instead, `new-feature master` is the third.

Comment: @jeff: no, you're correct, `master` is a separate (fourth) argument, `new-feature` is a third argument. It's just an optional starting point for the new branch. If you omit that fourth argument, Git uses `HEAD` as the starting point.

Comment: @torek thanks, so it will create a new branch called `new-feature` from `master`.

Comment: @Jeff And it will also checkout and switch to that new branch `new-feature`.